# Central Forces in Spherical Polar Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I know this isn’t how StackExchange works, but I needed to comment on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567923/applied-mathematics-spherical-polar-coordinates-and-newtons-second-law) and I don’t have enough reputation to do so (or enough time to gain enough).

I intended to ask why it is sufficient to show only that the $\phi$ component is equal to $0$. I understand how to show that $r^2\dot\phi\sin^2\theta$ being constant means that the $\phi$ component is $0$, but I couldn’t work out how to show that this also means the $\theta$ component is equal to $0$, despite the answer to the linked question implying that the $\theta$ component doesn’t necessarily have to equal $0$.

Also, I’m aware that this question probably counts as a duplicate, but I couldn’t see another way of asking without somehow gaining 42 reputation in less than two hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's given in the problem that the acceleration is radial only, so we know acceleration in the $\phi$ and $\theta$ components are both $0$. As it turns out, to solve the problem, all we need is that acceleration in the $\phi$ component is $0$; the fact that acceleration in the $\theta$ component is $0$ is extraneous information.

Comment: Thank you! I had been assuming that $r^2\dot\phi\sin^2\theta$ is constant and using that to prove that the $\phi$ and $\theta$ components are zero, when I should have been doing the reverse.

Comment: @TomHanney You're welcome!